# After spliting column values and how assign into to specific multiple column using R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

dataframe in R looks like this

```
**NAME**      |   MONTH
jana|   19-25| jan,mar,sep,dec
pugal|  45-50| april,may,june
--
```

and i want my answer should look

```
jana|   19-25|  jan
jana|   19-25|  mar
jana|   19-25|  sep
jana|   19-25|  dec
pugal|  45-50|  april
pugal|  45-50|  may
pugal|  45-50|  june
```

Comment: I am not sure if  undestood, but maybe this is what you are lokking for

`a=data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df),'|',fixed=TRUE)))
b=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, apply(a, 1, function(x) {
      do.call(expand.grid, strsplit(x, " *, *"))`

Answer (score -1):

This does what you want

```
n=c("jana| 19-25| jan,mar,sep,dec", "pugal| 45-50| april,may,june")

df = data.frame(n)

a=data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$n),'|',fixed=TRUE)))
b=as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, apply(a, 1, function(x) { do.call(expand.grid, strsplit(x, " *, *"))})))
```

Comment: i apologize for very basic level question...i am new to R, @S Revero thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score -1):

`separate_rows` in dplyr can do that:

```
library(tidyr)

DF %>% separate_rows(MONTH)
```

The result is:

```
   NAME RANGE MONTH
1  jana 19-25   jan
2  jana 19-25   mar
3  jana 19-25   sep
4  jana 19-25   dec
5 pugal 45-50 april
6 pugal 45-50   may
7 pugal 45-50  june
```

**Note:** The input data shown in the question has two column headings but three columns so we used this instead:

```
Lines <- "NAME | RANGE | MONTH
jana| 19-25| jan,mar,sep,dec
pugal| 45-50| april,may,june"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks its working great....but i think i works only with the install.packages("tidyr")
library(tidyr)

Comment: Have fixed now.